# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call()... After updating Jenkins from version 2.346.3 to 2.387.2

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

After updating Jenkins from from version 2.346.3 to 2.387.2. The pipelines with Groovy started failing when trying to build with this error message:

```
Also:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [[:], apps/kamala, cucumber]
Possible solutions: wait(), chars(), any(), trim(), collect(), find()
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:159)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at WorkflowScript.cmd(WorkflowScript)
        at WorkflowScript.tests(WorkflowScript:86)
Also:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [[:], apps/clavel, cucumber]
Possible solutions: wait(), chars(), any(), trim(), collect(), find()
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:159)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at WorkflowScript.cmd(WorkflowScript)
        at WorkflowScript.tests(WorkflowScript:87)
```

I thought it was due to an issue in the parameters passed to the methods but the pipeline is still working fine with the older version of Jenkins.

Also with Jenkins some plugins have been updated too. Main pluguins updated:

- Pipeline: Groovy Libraries from Version 612.v84da_9c54906d to 629.vb_5627b_ee2104
- Pipeline: Groovy form version 2759.v87459c4eea_ca_ to 3641.vf58904a_b_b_5d8
- Script Security from version 1175.v4b_d517d6db_f0to 1229.v4880b_b_e905a_6
- Pipeline Utility Steps form version 2.13.0 to 2.15.1

Any idea where the error could be?

Comment: Please update your question with the part of the code that fails